# NextAuth v4 - JWT_SESSION_ERROR

Tags: next.js, next-auth

This is the error :

```
[next-auth][error][JWT_SESSION_ERROR] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#jwt_session_error 
Invalid Compact JWE {  
message: 'Invalid Compact JWE',   
stack: 'JWEInvalid: Invalid Compact JWE
```

I met this error while migrating to v4. I saw this in the [documentation](https://next-auth.js.org/errors#jwt_session_error) :

> If you are unable to use an HS512 key (for example to interoperate
> with other services) you can define what is supported using

```
  jwt: {
    signingKey: {"kty":"oct","kid":"--","alg":"HS256","k":"--"},
    verificationOptions: {
      algorithms: ["HS256"]
    }
  }
```

But I don't get in which file I should put it. In which file this should go ?

Answer (score 0):

The file is api/auth/[...nextauth].js

You have to pass it into the `NextAuth` function. I found it [here](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/options#json-web-token-options).

Comment: This does not work in v4.
https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/upgrade-v4#jwt-configuration